# Component registration override

Tags: autofac

We produce a toolkit that can be supported by various IoC containers, the toolkit is fully IoC-agnostic and we provide basic support for different containers.
We are currently working to support Autofac, what we need is to allow end users to override our configuration, some part, that is based on conventions.

I'll explain what happens with Windsor so to understand if there is a similar mechanism with Autofac.

The toolkit provides a set of built-in services/component that are "automagically" registrated in the end-user container. With Windsor we register everything as "Fallback" so that if the user register something with the same service as "Default" the user component is resolved overriding our registration.

The interesting thing of this approach is that it works regardless of the order in which components are registered.

Any way to achieve the same behavior with Autofac?
.m

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think you're looking for the `PreserveExistingDefaults` extension. You can read more about it in the Autofac wiki: https://code.google.com/p/autofac/wiki/ComponentCreation

Comment: Good point but I have no control, well I'd like to not have any control, on the registration order.

Comment: but...due to the nature of autofac, where by default last win, may be it is much easier to take control over install/configure order.

Answer (score -1):

What happens if you remove the IOC container entirely?

You might need a different pattern here. If you want a container agnostic default registration, you need to think of the code itself being container agnostic, not having a fallback which is registered in the container.

You could use poor mans DI. (Although, you might want to orchestrate the creation and substitution of these default dependencies in one place, so the below might not be suitable, a factory could handle that though).

```
public SomeConstructor(IService service)
{
    if(service == null)
    {
        service = new DefaultService();
    }
}
```